# Why can't i assign a returned function to a class-member but can assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, member, assign

So i'm new to Javascript, and i have a problem that does not make sense to me.
I can't assign a function to a class member but i can assign it to a variable.
But i can assign a lambda to a class member.

What is the difference between the function returned by d3.scaleLinear() and a lambda? And why can i assign one but not the other to my class member?

d3.scaleLinear() returns a function that mapps the domanin values (in this case -1, 0, 1 ... 5) to the range (in this case a shade of black).

So this works:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        var color = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([-1, 5])
            .range(["hsl(0,00%,70%)", "hsl(0,0%,0%)"])
            .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
        alert(color(1));
    }
}
var bar = new Foo();
```

And this works too:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.color = () => alert("Test")
        color();
    }
}
var bar = new Foo();
```

Why is this not working:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.color = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([-1, 5])
            .range(["hsl(0,00%,70%)", "hsl(0,0%,0%)"])
            .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
        alert(this.color(1));
    }
}
var bar = new Foo();
```

Comment: What's the error you recieve when trying the code that doesn't work? Or if no error, what's the output?

Comment: Looks like my replied-to-answer was deleted. I'm not getting any errors, and I get a popup of "rgb(115, 115, 115)" as a result of your "not working" code. What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error i recive: "this.color is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code works for me. This minimal test case provides an alert with "rgb(115, 115, 115)" as the string.

If you're trying to use classes in an inheritance structure, you might need to call `super();` at the start of your constructor to access the inherited attributes, but for an assignment on a base class provided your code works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.color = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([-1, 5])
            .range(["hsl(0,00%,70%)", "hsl(0,0%,0%)"])
            .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
        alert(this.color(1));
    }
}
var bar = new Foo();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Unless you can provide more information (like what errors you're getting, or your current output vs expected output) we cannot help you.